# reverse N number of bits of a Byte from given position

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

In a given 8 bits/32 bits, from the given bit higher position,  reverse the bits upto the given lower position and save it.
Example,
**Reverse_specific_bits(char *data, int pos, int num_of_bits)**

Position – 5

Number of bits to be reversed = 5

Given data –   01**01101**1

Resultant bit - 01**10110**1

Anyone please help me to write a function for this.

Regards,
Vignesh

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a coding-services website, here we help people that run into a technical issue while coding. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way of doing this is,

1. Save the prefix fix and post fix of bits that don`t change in two separate queues.
2. Iterate over the bits that need to be reversed and push them to a stack.
3. Get a new queue and push the prefix bits queue then the stack and finally the post fix queue.

This is a very naive and simplest way of doing this. There are many efficient ways of doing this.